# Powershell can't access SQL Server 2012 Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap

Tags: powershell, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a powershell script to execute a dtsx package that is already on the server. Installing the package wasn't an issue but executing is proving rather frustrating.
Everything I've found online states that I need to load the ManagedDTS assembly and start with the following command to instantiate the required base object:

```
$dtsapp = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application")
```

But whenever I run this line I get the following error

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Could not load file or      assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At C:\Users\admin\Documents\test-ssis-dtsx.ps1:4 char:11
+ $dtsapp = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application")
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :   ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I've loaded the ManagedDTS assembly using these two ways:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS")
```

and

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
```

Both commands execute without issue but instantiating the object still fails. The DtsRuntimeWrap.dll is present on the system, just not in the GAC_MSIL folder (where the ManagedDTS.dll is). I am hesitant to start copying dlls across because I want to run this script on remote servers and I don't want to have to add these kinds of configuration steps to each server if I don't have to.

The machine I'm running this on is a fresh install of Windows 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2012 SP1. I'm using powershell 3.0.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Any idea what might cause this error?

Apparently the DTSRuntimeWrap is available in the GAC_32 folder. I tried copying it to the GAC_MSIL folder and running:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0, Cu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], BadImageFormatException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Also tried running these commands on a fresh Windows 2012 R2 box (with SQL Server 2012 SP1). Here I got the exact same errors, so the issue seems to be SQL Server 2012 related.

Comment: Did you copy over the DLLs, or did you install the complete Integration Services on that machine? If you just copied the DLLs they may be trying to talk to integration services... Also, AFAIK, every machine that you execute SSIS packages on needs to have an integration services license.

Comment: When I installed SQL Server 2012 I run it with all features with defaults, didn't copy seperate dll's. Not aware of any special SSIS license though. The SQL Server instance has a license. Furthermore when I run the package locally through DTExec it runs fine. Lastly, I don't even get to the package. Instantiating the DTS Application object causes the error.

Comment: Ok I just mentioned the licence because you mentioned running this on a bunch of remote servers :-). As for the DTS Object... Are you sure its DTSRuntimeWrap, not DTSPipelineWrap that you are looking for? I've got a few C# apps that run packages, they use DTSPipelineWrap and ManagedDTS, both located in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\

Comment: The error is caused by the '$dtsapp = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application")' line and the error it outputs refers to DTSRuntimeWrap... Which is also present in that same folder. But Powershell just can't seem to access it.

Comment: Try adding it manually to the GAC with gacutil maybe?

Answer (score 0):

We use the following to run SSIS commands from PowerShell:

SSISCommand is set to:

for 64-bit:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "c:\path\package.dtsx" /Reporting V
```

for 32-bit:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f c:\path\package.dtsx" /Reporting V
```

And run from PowerShell with:

```
Command.Run SSISCommand, 2, true
```

Comment: I have used this method as well and it does work. However, when I try to execute it over WinRM it fails claiming memory issues. It appears that WinRM runs it's tasks in an object with very little resources. Because of this I am pursuing a "powershell-only" approach using a dtsx package already on the server.

Comment: Just tried this approach using the /SQL parameter to execute the package on the server. This resulted in an erroneous execution when executed over WinRM.